# Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, android-studio

my project is based on both application ios and as well as android but if i work on window application and code pushed on github and then try to pull on mac they gives multiple errors in xcode not working .

error: Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')

i try to clean

1. sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
2. pod deintegrate
3. pod clean
   4.rm Podfile

5 update also
but not working in mac they gives error
Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.